# space time contraction

Tags: speed-of-light

What could be the reason that space and time contraction increases almost exponentially at the last decimals places close to the speed of light or close to singularity gravitational fields. Does this hint like a "sound barrier"
transistion wich is shown by the imposibility of mass particles to reach that speed and where massless particles navigate at this speeds. Would this imply that negative mass particles would be able to navigate at greater speeds than that of light.

Answer (score 0):

The space-time distortion gets greatly amplified near the limit because thats a mathematical property of the lorentz factor or the swcharzschild factor. Physically it means that it becomes progressively difficult to reach or surpass that limit. The concept of negative mass to me should accompany its own concepts of velocity and kinetic energy which implies that they could possibly have a different speed limit.